# Filling only height/3 of a square

Tags: pgfplots

How can I color only height/3 of a square? I know only how to fill the whole square:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=blue](0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=blue](0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4/3) -- (0,4/3) -- (0,0);
        \draw(0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]